# Reset changepassword control in ASP.Net under medium trust

Tags: c#, asp.net, medium-trust

A ChangePassword Control does not let us change the password multiple times in succession.

The control never shows its text boxes after the first time. I found a fix here (http://msmvps.com/blogs/egoldin/archive/2007/10/30/reseting-changepassword-control.aspx) but it wont work under medium trust.

Any ideas how can i reset my ChangePassword control in medium trust

Answer (score 1):

using Reflector is often better than reflection ;)

IControlDesignerAccessor control = (IControlDesignerAccessor)ChangePassword;
Hashtable table = new Hashtable(1);
table["CurrentView"] = 0;
control.SetDesignModeState(table);